# Aptana will not start on Elementary 0.2 (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: aptana, ubuntu-12.04

I am running elementary 0.2 (Ubuntu 12.04 but with a different desktop environment) and I installed [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) as follows:

```
sudo unzip /home/connel/Downloads/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.3.0.zip -d /opt
sudo mv /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/ /opt/aptana
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /opt/aptana/
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/aptana.desktop
```

But I cannot get it to run no matter what. I get no error codes when running the following but Aptana doesn't open:

```
cd /opt/aptana/
./AptanaStudio3
sh AptanaStudio3.sh
```

I have installed the JDK on my system, Netbeans runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you've downloaded the right platform version? I mean `32 bit` or `64 bit`.

To see the version you've downloaded do:

```
 file /opt/aptana/AptanaStudio3
```

Then check if your installation is `32 bit` or `64 bit`, do:

```
 uname -m
```

If you get `i686` is a normal `32 bit installation` if you get `i686_64` is a `64 bit installation`

For example I get:

```
      AptanaStudio3: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

Comment: file /opt/aptana/AptanaStudio3 gives me:
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

uname -m gives me:
x86_64

However I definitely downloaded "Aptana Studio 3.3.0
Linux, x64"

Comment: just downloaded the x86 version and I get ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64... they must have their website downloads the wrong way round!